# Creating a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need help creating a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER on mySQL Bench. im new to this please.

```
CREATE TABLE `quincyninying`.`toytracking` (
`Toyid` INT NOT NULL,
`ToyName` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`Toycost` DECIMAL NULL,
`ToyAction` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`ActionDate` DATETIME NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Toyid`));

CREATE TABLE `quincyninying`.`toy` (
`Toyid` INT NOT NULL,
`ToyName` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
`Toycost` DECIMAL NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Toyid`));
```

Create a BEFORE INSERT trigger on the toy table that adds a record to the toytracking table with the information from the toy table record that is being INSERTED, hard coded ToyAction that will be ‘INSERT’ and the current Date and time the record is inserted.

```
ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'inserted' in 'NEW' SQL Statement:
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `quincyninying`.`toy_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `toy` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.inserted THEN
        SET @toyaction = 'DELETE';
    ELSE 
        SET @toyaction = 'NEW';
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO `quincyninying`.`toytracking` (toyId, ToyName, ToyCost,     Toyaction, ActionDate)
    VALUES       (new.toyid, new.Toyname, new.Toycost,@Toyaction, now());

END
```

It throws me an error saying " ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'inserted' in 'NEW' "

Comment: It's pretty clear. You don't have column named 'inserted' on `TOY` table. What you want to achieve? And also, your tables design are not common. There are redundant information between those two tables.

Comment: i want to a BEFORE INSERT trigger on the toy table that adds a record to the toytracking table with the information from the toy table record that is being INSERTED, hard coded ToyAction that will be ‘INSERT’ and the current Date and time the record is inserted.

Comment: What is `IF new.inserted` supposed to be testing?

Comment: The question says that `ToyAction` should be `INSERT`. But your trigger sets it to either `DELETE` or `NEW`, depending on that test of a nonexistent column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `IF new.inserted` test, since there's no column with that name, and just hard-code `INSERT` as the value for the `ToyAction` column as you stated in the requirements.

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `quincyninying`.`toy_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `toy` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `quincyninying`.`toytracking` (toyId, ToyName, ToyCost, Toyaction, ActionDate)
    VALUES (new.toyid, new.Toyname, new.Toycost, 'INSERT', now());
END
```

Comment: Thank u Barmar. this is totally different from SQL. i am new to MySQL. can you please give me an example if it was a BEFORE UPDATE trigger? Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar ... I have also got stuck in similar situation.. do we have any option to delete column value in `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER`. Like in this example can we delete `new.inserted` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER toy_before_insert BEFORE INSERT 
    ON toy
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.Toyaction THEN
            SET @Toyaction = 'DELETE';
        ELSE
            SET @Toyaction = 'NEW';
        END IF;

        INSERT INTO toytracking (toyId, ToyName, ToyCost, Toyaction, ActionDate) VALUES (NEW.Toyid, NEW.ToyName, NEW.ToyCost, @Toyaction, NOW());

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Why should he try it? What is `NEW.deleted`? There's no `deleted` column in the `toy` table

Comment: Yes. i got it now this is my mistake.

Comment: Please any help it it was BEFORE UPDATE trigger? thank you

Comment: @ninying90 use `ELSEIF` more about https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/loops/if_then.php